# Resources discussing entanglement spectrum for specific systems

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement

I was currently reading the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0332) by Li and Haldane that describe the entanglement spectrum. I have read and derived the entanglement spectrum for critical systems by reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3059) by Calabrese; however, are there any resources that that describe entanglement spectrum for noncritical, gapped systems? It will be helpful if the resources give worked out examples of entanglement spectrum calculations for specific systems.